# Could not install p4eclipse in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev, p4eclipse

I am using eclipse 4.6 with pydev and p4eclipse plugins, my eclipse got crashed and now I do not have p4eclipse plugin, also when I try to install p4eclipse there is no  Install new software option in Help-> menu, also when I click on Help->Search->Install new software and get the link nothing happens when I click on it , please help

Comment: In the _Help > Install New Software..._ dialog there is an option _Hide items that are already installed_. Uncheck it to verify if you have already the latest version from the p4eclipse update site. Be aware, that in some perspectives (_Window > Perspective > ..._) some menus, icons, etc. are hidden. Therefore, please explain why you believe that the plugin is no longer available in your Eclipse installation.

Comment: @howlger - see when I open eclipse I see the perspective in available perspectives but when I switch workspace I do not see that perspective and could not see option to add new software too